# Получить атрибут из динамически созданного элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Инпут из динамически созданного элемента:

```
<input type="button" data-modelid="{{ service.model_id }}" value="add service" class="add_service_model">
```

Скрипт  вызова:

```
$('.firm_block').on('click', '.add_service_model', function(event){  

    var modelId = $(this).data('modelid');
    console.log( modelId );
});
```

Ничего не выдаёт.

Но `$(this).val()` возвращает значение `add service` (значение кнопки)

Comment: Что значит *Ничего не выдаёт.*?

Comment: Ни undefined, просто пустую строку, если можно так выразится. В "service.model_id"  значение есть.

Comment: Ничего не выдает, потому-что нет события нажатия на кнопку, у вас ошибка при его объявлении

Comment: @RifmaMan ну раз console.log выдает пустую строку, событие таки срабатывает.

Comment: Посмотрите в devTools в хроме (или любом другом инспекторе), что находится в дата-атрибуде `data-modelid`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, в том то и дело что ничего не выдает, проверьте его пример на редакторе кода если не верите!!!

Comment: @RifmaMan а почему оно может не работать? Можете посмотреть пример https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/qnh503gr/1/

Comment: Скорее всего у вас `service.model_id` все таки равен null или пустой.

Comment: Значение этой переменной дополнительно выводится и в других местах, и видно что она содержит необходимые данные.

Comment: @Stark посмототрите инспектор, посмотрите там значение `data-modelid` у вашего элемента. Единственный случай, когда консоль будет писать пустую строчку это когда `data-modelid=""`.

Comment: @RifmaMan срабатывает и alert().

Comment: @RifmaMan а вы посмотрели пример на `jsfiddle.net`? Там разве событие не срабатывает?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, Срабатывает. Но в там все элементы на странице располагалась изначально.

Comment: @Stark Это ничего не меняет. Вы напрочь игнорируете мой совет посмотреть инспектор кода. Почему?

Comment: Как бы мы не зашли в тупик с таким автором вопроса ))

Answer (score 0):

Событие нужно присваивать всему документу в котором находится объект (возьмите себе за правило - `$(document).on(...)`):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add_service_model', function(event) {
  var modelId = $(this).data('modelid');
  console.log(modelId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" data-modelid="123" value="add service" class="add_service_model">
```

Comment: Предполагал и такой вариант, но  ` firm_block ` находится на странице до генерации новых элементов, поэтому в принципе привязать можно и через него. (проверил и ваш вариант - разницы нет)

Comment: @Stark Вам удалось решить проблему? Задача выполнена? Если да, засчитайте ответ, если он не устраивает вас, удалите вопрос, если что-то не понятно или хотите разъяснений - задавайте!

Comment: Я же написал комментарий: разницы нет, то есть есть ваш вариант также не срабатывает.

Comment: @Stark давайте подведем итог, я немного запутался с вашей логикой, если вставить `alert()` в событие или скажем `$(this).val()` вы получаете сообщение/значение а если `console.log(modelId)` то ничего не видите в консоле Компонентов разработчика (клавиша F12)? вы в курсе что делает `console.log()` и увидеть результат работы этой функции?

Answer (score 0):

Такая запись не будет работать... `$('.firm_block').on('click', '.add_service_model'` ... или тут, или там. А вот запись такого вида:

```
$('.class').on('click'...);
```

Срабатывает только для тех классов, которые уже оказались на странице до загрузки скрипта. Для динамически созданных элементов пишут в таком виде:

```
$(document).on('click', '.class', function(){ ... });
```

```js
$('#create').on('click', function(){  
  $('#moo').append('<button class="yes">Работает</button>');
  $('#moo').append('<button class="no">Не работает</button>');
});

$('.no').on('click', function(){
  console.log('Я не работаю...');
});

$(document).on('click', '.yes', function(){
  console.log('Кто не работает - тот ест!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="create">Создать</button>

<div id="moo"></div>
```

Comment: Класс ` '.firm_block' ` находится на странице до генерации новых элементов. И событие срабатывает.

Comment: Почему запись такого вида не будет работать?

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME, лучше привязывать событие к ближайшему родителю, иначе если автор где-нибудь в будущем будет использовать такой же класс, то это вызовет неприятные последствия.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){
  $('.content').append('<button class="add">+</button><br>');
});

$('.content').on('click', '.add', function(){
  let i = $('.content').find('.remove').length;
  $('.content').append('<button class="remove" data-index="'+i+'">-</button>');
  
});

$('.content').on('click', '.remove', function(){
  let i = $(this).data('index');
  console.clear();
  console.info(i+' удалён');
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
button {
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add {
  background: green;
}

.remove {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content"></div>
```